# Maven package resources with classes

Tags: java, maven, resources

I'm generating a War file with Maven and publishing the classes jar as well:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is it also possible to publish the resources from the war in the classes jar?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "publish"? It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to pull them in as a dependency in another project.

Comment: So you're saying you want to be able to use the war's resources in another project?

Comment: That would be a good way to put it, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to put these resources in their own separate jar module and then have the war use them as a dependency.  That way the war and any other project could refer to the resources as if it was any other dependency.

But if you don't want to do that or you can't, I think you'll have to use a [classifier](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html). [As I said, this isn't ideal.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8041292/61624)  [Here's a detailed tutorial on how to do it](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/):

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>only-library</id>
            <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>only-library</classifier>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/Main*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>everything</id>
            <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>everything</classifier>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```